# A problem in probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

16 players, $S1,S2...S16$ are divided into eight pairs. What's the probability of only one of $S1$ or $S2$ coming out as one of the eight quarterfinalists?

To clarify, only one of them qualify. And all players are of equal strength. And, the pairings are completely random.

Comment: Clearly this depends on the tournament rules.  If $S_1$ plays $S_2$ in the first round then it is impossible that both of them make it through.

Comment: @lulu, I did clarify. Only one of them makes it.

Comment: Are you stipulating that $S_1$ and $S_2$ play each other in the first round?

Comment: They may, or may not. Both cases may result in only one of them qualifying.

Comment: So, then, you are assuming that all possible pairings are equally probable?  (If so, I think that ought to be added to the question.  It is not obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way for this is to split into two cases, based on whether P1 is paired with P2 on the first round.  The probability of that pairing is $\frac{1}{15}$ since each possible opponent for P1 is equally likely.  If that pairing happens, it is certain that exactly one of those players will qualify.

For the remaining $\frac{14}{15}$ of the time, the probability that exactly one will qualify is $\frac12$ since you have two independent "fair coin tosses."

The answer is
$$
\frac{1}{15} + \left( \frac12\right) \left( \frac{14}{15} \right)=\frac{8}{15}
$$

Comment: And that seems to be the correct answer. Thanks. I had problems with comprehending the situation.